# Why You Can't Compare STR to INT With IF/ELSE Statements & Work-Arounds

Tags: python

**//// This was my 2 different approaches to solving leetcode.com/problems/fizz-buzz \\**

**Here, I tried to get help for the following problem; but all I got was irrelevant answers**

So, I will try to explain why you can't compare str to int with if/else statements. If you run the code will get

> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

I am getting "n" which is int from the outside of the function. I need to first create a list then replace every number that that is divisible by 3 with "fizz" if it's by 5 with "buzz" if both 5 and 3 then "fizzbuzz"

Like so;

given n is 3 => answer = [1, 2, "Fizz"]
given n is 5 => answer = [1, 2, "Fizz", 4, "Buzz"]

You get the idea...

The problem I ran into is when use "if" I can replace the 3 with "Fizz" but it becomes this: **answer =[1, 2, "Fizz", 4, 5]**

If I use another "if" I get, typeerror: *not all arguments converted during string formatting*, because "Buzz if" (the if that checks answer[i] % 5 == 0) can't compare a int to string.

So I thought if I can learn the indexes of all fizz, buzz, and fizzbuzz

I can replace them like line 6 to line 8.  [My pic here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVeBS.png)

Could I use "if" to learn index?

**---- Edit1 ---**

I have managed to solve the problem but my code is a bit slow.

**My solution;**

```
def fizzbuzz(n):
answer = []
fizz_lst = []
buzz_lst = []
fizzbuzz_lst = []
for i in range(n):
    answer.append(i+1)
    if answer[i] % 3 == 0 and answer[i] % 5 == 0:
        fizzbuzz_lst.append(answer[i])
    if answer[i] % 3 == 0:
        fizz_lst.append(answer[i])
    if answer[i] % 5 == 0:
        buzz_lst.append(answer[i])
    for i in range(len(fizzbuzz_lst)):
        if fizzbuzz_lst[i] in answer:
            ourindx = fizzbuzz_lst[i]
            answer[ourindx - 1] = "FizzBuzz"
    for i in range(len(buzz_lst)):
        if buzz_lst[i] in answer:
            ourindx = buzz_lst[i]
            answer[ourindx - 1] = "Buzz"
    for i in range(len(fizz_lst)):
        if fizz_lst[i] in answer:
            ourindx = fizz_lst[i]
            answer[ourindx - 1] = "Fizz"
int_str = [str(x) for x in answer]
return int_str
```

I will try to improve my code and add edit2

**--- EDIT2  ---**

Well, I have managed to solve the problem "better" this time. When I Check Every iteration I use if/elif statements to set a int to a str but the problem was when the other elif statement check every iteration, those that % 3 == 0 would be changed to a str.

For example:

n is 5

We create a list that range(1,n+1,1)

This way the list is [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] Not [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

If we try our conditions with if statements, the list will go like this:

[1, 2, 3]  => [1, 2, "Fizz",]

But the problem here is when the statement if every_iteration % 5 == 0 line runs, we encounter a problem because every_iteration is a str now. We can't compare a int to str.

So the way I solved this "better" this time:

1. I thought if I can find a way to jump over str's in the list, I
   wouldn't miss anything because any int that got changed into str
   satisfied our if/elif statements.
2. So, if every_iteration is not a int, we just skip it.
3. This way, we do not need to run str thru if/elif statements.

**My full soliton 2 code;**

```
class Solution(object):
def fizzBuzz(self, n):
    answer = []
    for i in range(n):
        answer.append(i + 1)
    for every_iter in answer:
        if type(every_iter) != int:
            continue
        elif every_iter % 3 == 0 and every_iter % 5 == 0:
            answer[every_iter-1] = "FizzBuzz"
        elif every_iter % 3 == 0:
            answer[every_iter-1] = "Fizz"
        elif every_iter % 5 == 0:
            answer[every_iter-1] = "Buzz"
    answer_str = [str(j) for j in answer]
    return answer_str
```

Comment: _I need to first create a list then replace every number in the list with "fizz", "buzz", or "fizzbuzz"._ If you're replacing every number, then why do your sample answers still include numbers?

Comment: Sorry, I meant every number that that is divisible by 3 with "fizz" if it's by 5 with "buzz" if both 5 and 3 then "fizzbuzz"

Comment: Is it a leetcode problem?
https://leetcode.com/problems/fizz-buzz/solution/

Comment: Yes but I wondered if I can get the Index info of a list with if statement.

Comment: This is one of the most common interview problems in existence It has been solved in every possible language in every possible way. Consider doing a little research, like simply googling `fizzbuzz`…you will find *tons* of answers.

Comment: There are many things that don't make sense in the code, and I also can't make much sense out of the question. Please take a step back, a deep breath, and try to think about the problem logically.

Answer (score 0):

Usually in the FizzBuzz practice you're given a list, here you're trying to generate a list that goes up to what I assume would be the user's input.

so what you could do is first generate the list of numbers using list compression.

```
def fizzbuzz(n):
    answer = [i for i in range(n)]
```

After that you can check your conditions using a for loop that iterates through each item in the list and rather than using .append and .pop functions, you can simply reassign the value of the variable.

i.e.

```
def fizzbuzz(n):
    answer = [i for i in range(n)]
    for j in answer:
        if j % 3 == 0:
            j = "Fizz"
```

and add the rest of the conditions

Complete answer would be

```
def fizzbuzz(n):
    answer = []
    for j in range(1, n+1):
        if j % 3 == 0 and j % 5 == 0:
            answer.append("FizzBuzz")
        elif j % 3 == 0:
            answer.append("Fizz")
        elif j % 5 == 0:
            answer.append("Buzz")
        else:
            answer.append(j)

    print(answer)

n = int(input())
fizzbuzz(n)
```

Comment: If I use another "if" I get, typeerror: not all arguments converted during string formatting, because "Buzz if" (the if that checks answer[i] % 5 == 0) can't compare a int to string.

Comment: Firstly, you want to use the elif statement as you're setting a second condition for the same variable. Secondly, the variable you're checking the answer for is "j". j is each item in the answer list so you don't need to call an index from answer.

You might want to enhance your understanding of the for loop before proceeding.

Comment: I tried the complete answer, the list created needs to start from 1 up to n for range(n+1) does the job no problem.  changed the FizzBuzz if statement to top because it's more specific. then renamed the rest to elif. the j = "Fizz" part doesn't work. if I change | j == "Buzz" | to | answer[j] = "Fizz" | I get  TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Answer (score -1):

Well, I have managed to solve the problem "better" this time. When I Check Every iteration I use if/elif statements to set a int to a str but the problem was when the other elif statement check every iteration, those that % 3 == 0 would be changed to a str.

For example:

n is 5

We create a list that range(1,n+1,1)

This way the list is [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] Not [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

If we try our conditions with if statements, the list will go like this:

[1, 2, 3] => [1, 2, "Fizz",]

But the problem here is when the statement if every_iteration % 5 == 0 line runs, we encounter a problem because every_iteration is a str now. We can't compare a int to str.

So the way I solved this "better" this time:

I thought if I can find a way to jump over str's in the list, I wouldn't miss anything because any int that got changed into str satisfied our if/elif statements.

So, if every_iteration is not a int, we just skip it.

This way, we do not need to run str thru if/elif statements.

My full soliton 2 code;

```
class Solution(object):
def fizzBuzz(self, n):
answer = []
for i in range(n):
    answer.append(i + 1)
for every_iter in answer:
    if type(every_iter) != int:
        continue
    elif every_iter % 3 == 0 and every_iter % 5 == 0:
        answer[every_iter-1] = "FizzBuzz"
    elif every_iter % 3 == 0:
        answer[every_iter-1] = "Fizz"
    elif every_iter % 5 == 0:
        answer[every_iter-1] = "Buzz"
answer_str = [str(j) for j in answer]
return answer_str
```